# how to host bootstrap locally in angular without using npm

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

i want to know how can i add bootstrap in my angular project without install it npm and without using CDN links , i want to host locally bootstrap 
and i put a folder in my project and then in src folder and give the link in the head section of my index.html file  like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css>
```

but this is not working i am fully aware other methods like npm install and CDN links but some how i can not add it please help me on this issue

Comment: As far as I understand, all you need is to download "Compiled CSS and JS" and keep the folder structure as it is and use them. Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js

Comment: For one thing, you put the path value inside the " " to assign it to href attribute

Comment: Put the css file in your assets folder and reference it correctly in your href

Comment: The ironic thing here is that CDN's feel like the relatively new way to deal with library's of js and css. Keeping these local was like the only way to do this back in my day <old_man_yells_at_clouds.gif>

Comment: Look like you having wrong path. Append bootstrap.min.css name with project name <link rel="stylesheet" href="/projectname/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">. To verify your correct path right click on browser(chrome)->inspect->network->click on bootstrap.min.css(left side)-> look at the(right side) "Request URL: http://localhost/projectname/bootstrap.min.css" then match with your project path.

Comment: thanks David it 's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just put the bootstrap folder into my assets folder and then link it to the head section in my index.html so it worked and all bootstrap css work fine here is the path  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css>` this is working and i think this is same as we use bootstrap.js and popper.js and jquery 
all files put in the assets folder and thin link it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your index file location href the correct path.

If you are looking only for CSS jsut add:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for JS related:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

assuming you have this bootstrap folder inside your current project.
It might prompt for jquery as well so you might need to download that file as well for complete offline usage when/if using JS.